# Flutter i18n plugin can not auto change language

Tags: flutter, internationalization

After install [Flutter i18n plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n) I have added 3 language .arb files.When I add `localeResolutionCallback:` I can get this this language pages.But without `localeResolutionCallback:` it is always in english.How to make app auto change language when I change device language?

lib/main.dart:

```
...
import 'package:hctodo/generated/i18n.dart';
import 'app.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() {
  ...
  return runApp(CupertinoApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        S.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
//      localeResolutionCallback: S.delegate.resolution(fallback: new Locale("ja", "JP")),
      home: MyApp()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
First declare the supported Locales:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;   
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en'), // English
        const Locale('he'), // Hebrew
        const Locale('de'), // Hebrew
        // ... other locales the app supports
      ],
      home: MyHomePage(title: ''),
    );
  }
}
```

Then `var _sysLng = ui.window.locale.languageCode;`
in your other file

Comment: it return null:```[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'languageCode' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: languageCode```